# What goes wrong if 77>602?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What goes wrong if 77>602? I tried in IE, Firefox and Chrome

```
function getMaxValue(data){
    var maxValue=0;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

        if(data[i].value>maxValue){
             console.log(data[i].value +">"+maxValue);
             maxValue=data[i].value;
         }
     }
console.log("MaxValue:"+maxValue);
return maxValue;


}
```

I get my data from a json:

```
[{
"keyword": "User: Allen-P",
"value": "602"
}, {
"keyword": "From: phillip.allen@enron.com",
"value": "598"
},
{
"keyword": "Date: 2001",
"value": "276"
},
{
"keyword": "Subject: Re:",
"value": "228"
},
{
"keyword": "Date: 2001 Apr",
"value": "77"
},
]
```

Needed to add some useless description for StackOverflow. Please help me;). The json file is a bit bigger and just an example.

Comment: Are you comparing integers or strings?

Comment: if(parseInt(data[i].value)>maxValue){ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are compared alphabetically even if they contain numbers. The character `'7'` comes after the character `'6'`, alphabetically, so indeed, in terms of strings, `"77" > "602"`.

The solution is to convert them to numbers first:

```
    if(parseFloat(data[i].value) > maxValue){
```

Or for sake of brevity, the unary `+` operator will also do this:

```
    if(+data[i].value > maxValue){
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently comparing an integer with a string, which doesn't reliably work in this situation.

Either change your JSON and unquote the values, or use the following code instead:

```
function getMaxValue(data){
    var maxValue=0;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

        if(parseInt(data[i].value) > maxValue) {
             console.log(data[i].value +">"+maxValue);
             maxValue=data[i].value;
         }
    }
    console.log("MaxValue:"+maxValue);
    return maxValue;
}
```

Also read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parseInt(value,10) to convert the value from a string to a number